# Calling constructor without assigning it to any variable c++

Tags: c++, constructor

This might be a very silly question, but I don't even know what should I write to look for answers. I'm not even sure if the title I gave is correct.

If I have a constructor like this:

```
CError(const std::string& msg) { showMessage(msg) }
```

And I'd like to call it like this ...

```
CError("some message");
```

... everything works, but when string is specified in some variable, I got an error that "Default constructor for class CError doesn't exist":

```
std::string str = "some message";
CError(str);
```

When I write it like this, it works:

```
std::string str = "some message";
CError err(str);
```

But I just don't need this `err` object.

Could anyone explain me why can't I call only constructor itself?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: For the same reason why you can't write `int = 5`, or `int(5)`?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Is this really the same? I'd rather say you're trying to assign object of type int to type itself, but I don't - I just want to create an object and not to have access to it (because I don't need it), I just need to call constructor which shows MessageBox for me.

And as I see, you actually can write just int(5).

Comment: No, `int = 5` isn't even remotely the same thing. `int(5)`, however, is, and it's legal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line `CError(str);` is parsed as `CError str;`, which defines a new variable, `str`. My compiler fails differently, which makes the problem more obvious: `redefinition of 'str' with a different type`.

A simple work-around for this problem is to cast the object:

```
(void)CError(str);
```

The burning question, however, is: why do this? If you don't plan to use the constructed object in any way, why not simply make it a static member function or even just a plain old free function?

Comment: This is very strange, but actually it makes sense! Thanks very much for the answer. :-)

And yes, I will make a static member function, but just was curious what the hell was wrong with this constructor.

Comment: @Mosquito: I've never fully grokked C's disturbed declaration syntax. I usually have pass these kinds of oddities through one or two compilers to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

The statement `CError(str);` is read as defining an object `str` of type `CError`; it's equivalent to `CError str;` but with the name `str` parenthesized.

To work around this you can parenthesize the type name as well: `(CError)(str);`.  This forces the statement to be read as a functional-cast expression; you could equivalently write `(CError) str;` or even `static_cast<CError>(str);`.

In C++11 you can use universal initialization syntax to write `CError{str};`.